# Auto-Layout Warnings: Frame for "foo" will be different at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, warnings

On my projects I'm constantly getting the warning: "Frame for "foo" will be different at run time" on my storyboards.

It seems like the slightest nudge to my mac knocks the views off by a pixel, leaving me to hunt down all the yellow dots and click "Update frames", "Apply to all views in container", and quite frankly I'm sick of it.

Can someone tell me if they've found a better way of dealing with these warnings than this?

Here are my top hypothetical solutions, in order:

1. Is there an option somewhere in Xcode to have it automatically update the misplaced frames rather than generating the warning?
2. Is there a way to update all the frames on a storyboard in one go? (instead of selecting it for each individual view controller)
3. Is there an Xcode plugin to do either of the above?
4. Is there a way to just hide this particular warning?

Or am I just doing something wrong to getting these errors all the time?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do it to ALL your view controllers at once. Automatically updating them wouldn't be possible, as you need to be able to lay things out as you set them up, so there will certainly be times you don't have constraints set up correctly.

Unfortunately the best way is probably the Update Frames feature, but as you noted - its per view controller.

Comment: Once you update all the frames to fix the yellow dots, they should stay fixed unless you move things or change the constraints. If the yellow dots magically reappear without any changes on your part (yes, I have seen this on occasion), check if any of your constraints have a constant that is not a whole number, such as 26.5 or 44.5. Select such constraints and change them to the nearest whole number, update frames, and see if the problem stays fixed.